# Regex true only if string fully contains various matches

Tags: regex

I'm trying to write a RegEx that matches a string under three conditions:

1) The whole string matches all or some of the capture groups defined in pattern

2) Capture groups do not have to be defined in the same order they appear in the pattern

3) Pattern can have an unknown number of capture groups that are NOT found in string

So some RegEx that includes the following capture groups...

```
(,101,)|(,10,)|(,203,)|(,542,)
```

I would expect the RegEx to match the following...

```
,203,10,101,
```

...because every bit of the string is somehow matched.

But I would NOT want it to match this string...

```
,203,684,10,
```

...because ,684, was not one of the groups specified.

This will be eventually fed into an SQL statement.  So I could potentially do the exact opposite of what I've stated and then make my SQL query NOT REGEX.  So essentially a double negative.

Comment: `(,101|,10|,203|,542)+,` ?

Comment: nope.  this will match if: ,203,684,10,

Comment: Where does that data structure come from? Those sounds like meta information, that should be stored normalized to begin with?

Comment: It comes from code developed by my genius brain, @CBroe.  Also keep in mind that this is a simplified version of the problem.  The real thing doesn't look quite like this.  So don't try and over-think how I got to this point.

Comment: _“So don't try and over-think how I got to this point”_ – I think the problem itself might be under-thought (about) so far  … [care to ellaborate maybe](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So... is this what you are looking for?

```
 /^,(101,|10,|203,|542,)+$/
```